# Add specific heading content only when the environment extends to several pages

Tags: environments, koma-script

I defined an environment in the following way:

```
\documentclass[
headsepline,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
\section{Title \arabic{mycounter}}
\markright{\textup{\textsf{Left \hfill Right on \arabic{mycounter}}}}
}{\stepcounter{mycounter} \newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
\blindtext
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I want to show the `Right` part in the heading if, and only if, the environment extends to several pages. If the environment fits on a single page, i want to show `Left` on the left in the heading but not `Right`. How can I do this?

Edit: The reason I want to do this is that I enumerate the several environments and want to show the number on following pages to indicate where the content belongs to but by avoiding redundant enumeration on the first page if there is only one (because the shown title already includes the environment counter).

Comment: To clarify, for a multi-page heading, should *every* page of the multi-page heading be marked right, or only the second onward?

Comment: It should be the same heading on every page.